# Wedding Guest Problem

Tags: statistics

Okay, say we have a wedding guest list and probabilities
of each person attending.

Think of this as a set with tuple elements in the form

(guest, probability attending)

example)

G = { (bob, 1.0), (emilio, 0.7), (emily, 0.7), ... }

Is there a way to calculate a kind of "most likely" set, call this set C,
of guests? Calculating the cardinality of C is trivial (I think). Our goal for C is the set that will most likely to occur out of all possible sets "generated" by G.

example)
C = { bob, emilio, emily, jill}

Edit:

One more thing is bugging me.
Say, we had a set of G = { (p1, 0.4), (p2, 0.4), (p3, 0.4) }
Wouldn't the "expected value" be 1.2?
But, our most probable set be the null set? 
So, what explains this 'mismatch'?

Answer (score 2):

If the probability is more than 0.5, expect the guest to be present in the most likely set. Otherwise, expect the guest to be absent.

This will maximize the likelihood.

Comment: However, what if we have a set G = { (p1, 0.3) , (p2, 0.25), ... (descending) }? (A very sad wedding indeed)

Comment: I believe empty set is more likely than anyone present in this case.

Comment: If G = { (p1, 0.3) , (p2, 0.25) }, we only have 4 cases to consider.
Pr(no body is there)=0.7(0.75)
Pr(only p1 is going)=0.3(0.75)
Pr(only p2 is going)=0.7(0.25)
Pr(both are going)=0.3(0.25)
I think the couple need to have something fun, such as a maths party to attract people there. Also, I am assuming that whether the decision to attend the wedding is independent from others' decision.

Comment: Thank you very much! This makes sense. I'm thinking also about when a person has a 50% chance of attending. I'm unsure of how that should be handled.

Comment: In that case we'd have multiple equally likely most probably sets.

Comment: expected value is an average, they take all possible outcome into considerations.

Answer (score 0):

For your edited question, the chance of 0 is .6^3 or .216. The flip side is a 79.4 chance of 1 or more guests. So the 1.2 projection is more accurate than defaulting to zero.