# Finding the mean age of a wedding guest list

Tags: statistics

Earlier I asked this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1763440/wedding-guest-problem).

So, similarly, imagine the same type of list with elements having a guest and probability of attending, but now each guest also has an age. How can we calculate the expected average age of the guests of the wedding?

I can heuristically group the guests into age ranges and then compute the expected number of people in each age range, but this doesn't tell me the expected mean.

Answer (score 1):

This is calculated in two parts:

1. Probability of a particular group attending.
2. Average age of that group.

For a list of $N$ guests, there are $N \choose k$ ways for $k$ people to attend. For each such group, you need to calculate the average age and the probability of that group attending. Assuming each person attends independently of the others, the probability of group $G$ is:

$$P(G)=\prod_{i\in G}p_i \prod_{i\notin G} (1-p_i)$$

So, we can calculate the average as:

$$\sum P(G)A(G)$$

Where $A(G)$ is the average age of the group $G$.

So, this calculation will involve a sum of a large number of terms.

Comment: Thank you very much! Are there any resources for these types of problems? Your solution does give the exact average, but as you noted it does involve a large number of terms --- so this algorithm would run in non-polynomial time noting we have to do computations on more than every permutation of the list. I think the approximate solution is also interesting.

Comment: @Daniel the closest I can think of is Compound Distributions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_probability_distribution. I'd have to give some thought to appropriate approximations. Obviously, you can create a CDF of the probability that someone with age $X$ will attend by ordering by age (increasing) and creating a cumulative sum. Honestly, I'd probably just use Monte Carlo simulation with, say, 10,000 trials.

Comment: @Daniel the problem is that you're drawing from two non trivial distributions: the binomial (number of people) and an arbitrary age distribution (without replacement).